# In Python, is object() equal to anything besides itself?

Tags: python

If I have the code `my_object = object()` in Python, will `my_object` be equal to anything except for itself?

I suspect the answer lies in the `__eq__` method of the default object returned by `object()`. What is the implementation of `__eq__` for this default object?

EDIT: I'm using Python 2.7, but am also interested in Python 3 answers. Please clarify whether your answer applies to Python 2, 3, or both.

Comment: This is a safe and idiomatic way to create a unique sentinel value.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks, I asked about this because I wanted a sentinel value, but didn't want to pollute such a simple question with my use case. The question stands on it's own.

Comment: @Buttons840 I don't see the point of using `__eq__` with a sentinel. If you want to check if something *is* the sentinel, python already provides the `is` operator which cannot be overloaded and thus it's the perfect choice for checking these kind of things. Use `==` only when you don't really care for identity, but for equality (and this is *not* generally true when using a sentinel value...)

Comment: @Bakuriu I wouldn't use == with a sentinel object itself, but some use cases involve implicit equality tests. I'm currently doing somelist[somelist.index(placeholderobject)] = non_placeholder_data for example, and I found this post while searching to make sure that would work on dummy objects.

Comment: Came here looking for whether using object() as sentinel is good practice. I've been using `class MySentinel(): pass`, but just realized that I could probably just `MySentinel = object()`. Thanks @Marcin and @Buttons840 for confirming my idea.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`object` doesn't implement `__eq__`, so falls back on the default comparison `id(x) == id(y)`, i.e. *are they the same object instance* (`x is y`)?

As a new instance is created every time you call `object()`, `my_object` will never* compare equal to anything except itself.

This applies to both 2.x and 3.x:

```
# 3.4.0
>>> object().__eq__(object())
NotImplemented

# 2.7.6
>>> object().__eq__(object())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#60>", line 1, in <module>
    object().__eq__(object())
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute '__eq__'
```

* or rather, as [`roippi`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23703933/3001761) points out, *hardly ever*, assuming sensible `__eq__` implementations elsewhere.

Comment: This answer might be clearer if you replace "this will never be the case" to a explicit sentence like "In your example, my_object will only be equal to itself, and will never be equal to anything else".

Answer (score 28):

`object().__eq__` returns the `NotImplemented` singleton:

```
print(object().__eq__(3))
NotImplemented
```

By the reflexive rules of [rich comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__), when `NotImplemented` is returned, [the "reflected" operation is tried](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy).  So if you have an object on the RHS that returns `True` for that comparison, then you can get a `True` response even though the LHS did not implement the comparison.

```
class EqualToEverything(object):
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return True

ete = EqualToEverything()

ete == object() # we implemented `ete.__eq__`, so this is obviously True
Out[74]: True

object() == ete # still True due to the reflexive rules of rich comparisons
Out[75]: True
```

**python 2 specific bit:** if *neither* object implements `__eq__`, then python moves on to check if either implement [`__cmp__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__).  Equivalent reflexive rules apply here.

```
class ComparableToEverything(object):
    def __cmp__(self,other):
        return 0

cte = ComparableToEverything()

cte == object()
Out[5]: True

object() == cte
Out[6]: True
```

`__cmp__` is gone in python 3.

In both python 2 and 3, when we exhaust all of these comparison operators and all are `NotImplemented`, the final fallback is checking identity.  (`a is b`)

Comment: Ah, an interesting exception I hadn't thought of!

Comment: Good point, the object on the left side of == determines which __eq__ method gets called, so order does matter.

Comment: Does the \__cmp__ function returning 0 indicate they are equal, such as ```3 - 3 == 0```?

Comment: [`__cmp__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) `Should return a negative integer if self < other, zero if self == other, a positive integer if self > other.`

Comment: One particular example where this might happen (though you'd be silly to use NumPy this way): `x = object(); if x == numpy.array([x]): print('Huh?')`