# Unique constant reference

Tags: python

Let's take as an example the following code :

```
ALL = "everything"

my_dict = {"random":"values"}

def get_values(keys):
    if keys is None:
        return {}
    if keys is ALL:
        return my_dict
    if not hasattr(keys, '__iter__')
        keys = [keys]
    return {key: my_dict[key] for key in keys}
```

The function `get_values` returns a dict with the given key, or keys if the parameter is an iterable, an empty dictionary if the parameter is None or the whole dictionary if the parameter is the constant ALL.

The problem with this happens when you would want to return a key called "everything". Python might use the same reference for ALL and the parameter (since they're both the same immutable), which would make the `keys is ALL` expression `True`. The function will therefore return the whole dict, so not the intended behavior.

It would be possible to assign `ALL` to an instance object of a class defined specifically for that purpose, or to use the `type` method to generate an object inline, which would make ALL a unique reference. Both solutions seem a little overkill though.

I could also use a flag in the function declaration (i.e. : `def get_values(keys, all=False)`), but then I can always derive the value of a parameter from the other (if `all is True`, then `keys is None`, if `keys is not None`, then `All is not False`), so it seems overly verbose.

What is your opinion on the previously mentioned techniques, and do you see other possible ways of fixing this ?

Comment: Are you asking what an appropriate *sentinel value* would be? Why not e.g. `ALL = object()`? This will be identical (and probably equal) to itself but nothing else (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23703899/3001761).

Comment: PEP 0020 dude, how about making a function called get_all_values()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use a value that could be (without extreme effort) a valid key as the sentinel.

```
ALL = object()
```

However, it seems much simpler to define the function to take a (possibly empty) sequence of keys.

```
def get_values(keys=None):
    if keys is None:
        keys = []
    rv = {}
    for key in keys:
        # Keep in mind, this is a reference to
        # an object in my_dict, not a copy. Also,
        # you may want to handle keys not found in my_dict:
        # ignore them, or set rv[key] to None?
        rv[key] = my_dict[key]
    return rv

d1 = get_all_values()   # Empty dict
d2 = get_all_values([])  # Explicitly empty dict
d3 = get_all_values(["foo", "bar"])  # (Sub)set of values
d4 = get_all_values(my_dict) # A copy of my_dict
```

In the last case, we take advantage of the fact that `get_all_values` can take *any* iterable, and an iterator over a `dict` iterates over its keys.